# How to remove duplicate elements from HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

Newbie here. Don't want to embarrass myself but I couldn't find a compelling solution while browsing responses to similar questions so I apologize for being a nuisance. I'm working on designing my neocities page and this is my first experience with HTML & CSS. Everything is turning out fine, except for some reason there's a duplicate box (?) at the very bottom of my page. Very sorry for the my disastrous & untidy code because I have little to no idea of what I'm dealing with. Please help me out if you have the patience. Sidenote: It seems to have appeared after I tweaked the margins of the buttons but I can't say for sure[The white space looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyHfn.png).
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>blog title</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <style>
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      </style>
      </head>
        <body>
                        <div class="box"></div>
        </body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>welcome</h1>
    <p>introducrion</p>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
                              <button class="button1">buttonname1</button>
            <button class="button2">buttonname2</button>
                        <button class="button3">buttonname3</button>
                        <button class="button4">buttonname4</button>
                                    <button class="button5">buttonname5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
            background-image: url('https://img.hmv.co.jp/image/jacket/400/79/1/8/014.jpg');
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.content{
    width: 700px;
    height: 680px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 30px;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
}
.style
            @font-face{
                font-family: 'Robotic Monkey';
                src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.woff2") format("woff2"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.woff") format("woff"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.ttf") format("truetype"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.svg#Robotic Monkey") format("svg");
            font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            .logo h1{
             font-family: Robotic Monkey;
                 font-size: 45pt;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
            }
@font-face{
    font-family: "Robotic Monkey";
    src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.woff2") format("woff2"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.woff") format("woff"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.ttf") format("truetype"), url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/8228af465877153a59194e55cb42ddce.svg#Robotic Monkey") format("svg");
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Robotic Monkey';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: monospace;
}
p{
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-align: center;
}
            div{
            background: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 25px;
            height: 680px;
}
.button1{
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;    
}
.button2{
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;    
}
.button3{
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;    
}
.button4{
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;    
}
.button5{
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 60px;
    min-width: 300px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    text-align: center;
    will-change: transform;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have any content (in your case `<div class="content">`) outside `body`

Comment: [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) might be a good starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two height values were present in this code.

1. class content having height: 680px;
2. button wrap container div having height: 680px;

For you mentioned issue, you need to remove the button wrap container div height.

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, set `div { height:auto }` then the duplicate box will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by two dives (.content, div) with different heights.

change the height of the div.

```
   div {
background: #ffffff;
border-radius: 25px;
height: 450px;
```

}